# django custom user model groups and permissions

Tags: django, permissions, usergroups, custom-authentication

I am trying to implement custom user model in my django application.

If I just copy and paste the code from [this article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example), it works great. But I wish this custom user model to have permissions and groups. So I added this inheritance to *models.py*:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
```

and these fields into the *admin.py* MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin) class:

```
('Permissions', {'fields': (
    'is_admin', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'groups', 'user_permissions',
)}),
```

But it looks strange for me:

[image: admin screenshot]

As I know, it must be two containers: left (that I have) that shows all available groups and permissions and right (that I don't have) that shows all current user's groups and permissions.

P.S. I tried google for it and found only one post on reddit which is 10 month old but doesn't have a solution.

Comment: did you get the answer?

Answer (score 5):

Deleting this line in *MyUserAdmin* class fixed the problem up.

```
filter_horizontal = ()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set argument in `filter_horizontal(ARGUMENT)`,
the argument is your field `manyToMany` in `model`.

Example:

```
class CustomUser(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):
    custom_groups = models.ManyToManyField('CustomUserGroups', blank=True)  

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
  filter_horizontal = ('custom_groups', )
```